# Rails: Why does update_attribute automatically convert types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, type-conversion, update-attribute

For example, say I have a User model with an integer column 'pet_id'.

If I run

```
user = User.new
user.update_attribute(:pet_id, '1')
```

It automatically converts the string '1' to an integer 1. Where does this conversion take place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the method responsible for the `type_cast` in active record

```
def type_cast(value)
    return nil if value.nil?
    return coder.load(value) if encoded?

    klass = self.class

    case type
    when :string, :text        then value
    when :integer              then klass.value_to_integer(value)
    when :float                then value.to_f
    when :decimal              then klass.value_to_decimal(value)
    when :datetime, :timestamp then klass.string_to_time(value)
    when :time                 then klass.string_to_dummy_time(value)
    when :date                 then klass.value_to_date(value)
    when :binary               then klass.binary_to_string(value)
    when :boolean              then klass.value_to_boolean(value)
    else value
    end
  end
```

To understand `rails` `activerecord` `type_cast` in details please visit these three sites

1) Thoughtbot blog [How Rails' Type Casting Works](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-rails-works-type-casting)

2) Ken Collins [ActiveRecord 4.2's Type Casting](http://technology.customink.com/blog/2015/01/06/activerecord-42s-type-casting/)

3) Rails `activerecord` typecast method in [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb#L91-L109)